# The event Listener is not working on my contact form

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to create a contact me form with React and I am getting the error of
`eventListener Null`
The database backend is hosted with firebase. 
My `index.js` code is below:

```
// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('submitForm').addEventListener('contactMeForm', submitForm);
```

And the corresponding contactMeForm code is below:

```
<Button variant="primary" type="contactMeForm" id="submitForm" addEventListener="contactMeform">
Submit</Button>
```

Comment: why dont add just a simple `onClick` to `Button` ?

Comment: Sorry new to React how would I tell the onClick to speak to the event listener

Answer (score 1):

What event are you trying to trigger ? when you click on the button? you don't have to call addEventListener in react.

Comment: I am trying to get an email sent to the DB when someone submits a question on a contact me form.